Pylint does not work in VB Code when editing a module in the virtualenv
I have a file in a module in a virtualenv directory, that I wish to edit in VS Code. If I tell Code to use the virtualenv in which the module resides, it will not show pylint suggestions. If I tell Code to use a different virtualenv, pylint suggestions are shown, but of course it complains that modules that I have added to the former virualenv are missing.
If I run pylint from the command  line, in the correct virtualenv, the correct suggestions are shown
How can I fix this?
